# how do I highlight rows with a certain phrase?

Tags: excel, vba

The place I work for has monthly numbers listed in an Excel spreadsheet. Every month my coworker has to find every row with the phrase `Jacobs Eng QP` and highlight the row manually. Is there a macro that could do this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select range

Click `Conditional Formatting` in the ribbon.

then `Equal to` and type *Jacobs Eng QP* in the input box.

[image]

[image]

---

VBA user-friendly solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightCells()

    Dim rangeToCheck As Range
    Set rangeToCheck = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

    Dim searchTerm As String
    searchTerm = InputBox("Enter search term")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rangeToCheck
        If InStr(1, cell, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

Additional resource:

- [Highlight cells based on a condition](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/highlight-cells-based-on-a-condition/)

Comment: + 1 nicely explained as usual :)

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much. If I wanted to highlight the whole row, could I change "cell" to "row"?

Comment: @user2665179 you could change it to `cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`. Please consider accepting this answer if its useful ::)

Comment: Thank you! I can't tell you how much time this is saving me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use custom formatting combined with a formula like INSTR() - I cannot guide you because my office Version uses totally diffferent keywords ( I love the translation of office...)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried HOME->Conditional formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> Text that contains ?