# 0 records in Excel sheet

Tags: excel

How to identify 0 records in an excel sheet by excel macro

```
Name   Month      Place    Salary

Ian    Jan.2014   USA      $10000

mia    Jan.2014   USA      $11000

shan   Jan.2014   USA       0

swil   Jan.2014   USA       0
```

What code required to identify salary with '0. records

Comment: like [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984319/how-do-i-highlight-rows-with-a-certain-phrase/18984420#18984420)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Conditional Formatting to hi-light the records or an AutoFilter to isolate them

Comment: + 1 For Auto filter :)