# How to filter by cell color?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2003

Some of my managers have access to Office 2010 or later. I know in the newer Office there is the option to filter by cell color. But on my floor we only have Office 2003. I am wondering is there a way I can filter by the fill of the cell?

The way I am doing it right now is create another column, putting an "x" manually on the highlighted rows. And then filter it with the "x". Is there a easier way to do this? (They have hundreds of rows like that). I am using Window XP with Excel 2003.

Comment: [**`iterate over cells if they match your criteria then highlight rows`**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/highlight-cells-based-on-a-condition/) or [*`the macro part here`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984319/how-do-i-highlight-rows-with-a-certain-phrase/18984420#18984420)

Comment: For xl2003, AFAIK (and I could be wrong) but you can't do that using any inbuilt functionality. You will have to use VBA to solve this.

Comment: There's no built-in functionality to do this in Excel 2003 but you can do it with macros. Use a macro to add your "x", and then you can filter by that column.

Comment: Not in 2003 by default, but if you install ASAP utilities, my answer has the procedure.

Comment: ...cost of ASAP Utilities might be better spent towards the cost of an Office upgrade...." correct only because you said might. If this was ASAP only feature you might be right, but it has many other features that excel does not. You can download ASAP for free, decide if you like it then buy.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install ASAP utilities http://www.asap-utilities.com/
2. Click on ASAP Utilities tab
3. Choose "Select" with the big mouse pointer over it
4. Choose "Select cells based on content, formatting and more...
5. go to the tab "Based on formatting and more"
6. Select "cell color" and choose the example cell which contains your color
7. Choose your cell range and choose entire row
8. click ok

This will allow you to select all the rows. Color the entire rows which are now selected. Find an empty column and use find/replace to find the color just added and replace it with an 'x'. Now you can filter in this new column for x, which is just like filtering on the original columns color. This is better so you don't have to add a new character to the existing column which might contain data.

Comment: Yes, you have to install ASAP utilities. My first answer no.