# I need to highlight values that are lower than a specified column in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel spread sheet with over 1,000 rows of inventory prices and I have two columns one showing our selling price and another showing what the target selling price should be to obtain a desired margin. I want to highlight any selling prices that are below the target price. Is there a simple formula I could use rather than go through line by line?

Comment: adjust to suit you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984319/how-do-i-highlight-rows-with-a-certain-phrase/18984420#18984420

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting to achieve this.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to highlight, you will need conditional formatting. If you only want to know which items have a margin below the required, you can use a simple expression in a new column.

Let's say column A has the items, column B has the selling prices and column C has the target selling prices.

---

Conditional formatting, let's say you want to highlight the item only:

- Select the column A with A1 as the active cell (Click A1, then click the column header "A". Cell A1 should be paler than the other selected cells)
- Open up conditional formatting with a new rule and use a formula to select which cells to format.
- Put the formula in the entry box:

  ```
  =$B1<$C1
  ```

  If the selling price `B1` is less than that of the target, it will return 'true'.
- Pick a conditional format and click OK.

If you want to highlight both the selling and target selling price, select the two columns B and C instead.

---

Using another column:

In a new column, column D, put the formula:

```
=B1<C1
```

And scroll the formula to the bottom. All those with selling price below the target selling price will be "TRUE" and "FALSE" otherwise. You can use a filter to get only those with selling price below the target selling price.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using 'Conditional Formatting'.

First of all, select the cells you want to highlight (e.g. 'B1:B950').
Then create a 'new Rule...' --> "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

After that you type in your formula (e.g. '=B1