# Conditional formatting and IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, formula, conditional-formatting

How do you include formatting included with an a IF statement. Such as this formula:

```
=IF([@[July Production Delivered]]<=[@[July Target Date]],
   "green", IF([@[July PP Presented]]>[@[July Target Date]],
   "Red", IF([@[July Total Days]]=0,"NULL","Yellow")))
```

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984319/how-do-i-highlight-rows-with-a-certain-phrase/18984420#18984420) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some exceptions, each different format in Conditional Formatting by formula requires a different rule. So for three colours (ie here green, red and yellow) three rules are required.

These three rules may be extracted from your formula as:

[@[July Production Delivered]]<=[@[July Target Date]] > green
[@[July PP Presented]]>[@[July Target Date]] > red
[@[July Total Days]]=0 > yellow (adjusted from your version)

Unfortunately for you (suits me, I hate structured references) such references cannot be used in Conditional Formatting without a hack. So I have assumed that your Table occupies columns as below:

ColumnA July Production Delivered
ColumnB July Target Date
ColumnC July PP Presented
ColumnD July Total Days

Select your Table data, HOME . Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=$A2<=$B2
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> and select green format, OK, OK. Repeat with:

```
=$C2>$B2
```

and select red format. Repeat with:

```
=$D2=0
```

and select yellow format.

If it is possible that more than one condition applies simultaneously you may need to order the sequence in which the rules are applied.